# Set RequestFocus on first EditText in a dynamic ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

At the moment im looping through a dynamic arraylist and building a Listview with Switches and Edittexts from its data.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); ++i) {
...
xxx.SetId(i)
...
}
```

this was my working solution if a Edittext was on the first position:

```
if (i == 0 ) {
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode (WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                }
```

But how to set the focus on the first available Edittext? for example third position after two switches?
(the position changes dynamically based on the arraylist)

Comment: ListView and user input don't like each other. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3061399/533873) for some explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should populate and set any required state inside the **Adapter** that is attached to the **ListView**. A simple solution would be something in the lines of:

```
public class MyAdapter extends Adapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, parent, false);
        // position is zero-based so 3rd item is at position 2
        if (position == 2) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.edittext).requestFocus();
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

And to scroll the listview to the 3rd item you could call `listView.setSelection(2)`.